# Datatable display problem using vue-axios and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatable, axios

Im using jQuery datatables for displaying my data in my users component in Vue.js, but when I run my code it displays the data but it has some text that says **"No data found"**. Can someone help me with this? I really don't have any idea because I'm new in this Frontend tools.

[image: table]

`Users.vue`:

```
<template>
  <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Created</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
        <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.type }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.created_at }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        type: ""
      })
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadUsers() {
      axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) => (this.users = data));
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("Component mounted.");
    this.loadUsers();
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table").DataTable({});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you should init your widget `DataTable` after receiving data from `api`, more precisely in `then` method.

```
axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) => {
  this.users = data;
  this.$nextTick(() => {
     $("#table").DataTable({});
  });
});
```

Explanation about [`Vue.$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#vm-nextTick):

> Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use
> it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM
> update. This is the same as the global `Vue.nextTick`, except that the
> callback’s `this` context is automatically bound to the instance calling
> this method.

Comment: how could I do that sir? can you show me some few codes so that I can play with it?

Comment: Oh ,yea, and don't forget to wait for DOM changes through `this.$nextTick`;

Comment: It works sir but it needs to be reloaded in order to work and it throws me an error `Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function"` then after I reload its gone. then when I click to other component  then go back, it shows again the error

Comment: I've read some info of the data table do I need to use `data: ` for displaying the data in the data tables sir?

Comment: Can you provide how you include this widget into the project?

Comment: what do you mean by that sir?

Comment: How do you include `DataTable`?

Comment: i just put the scripts in my `master.blade.php` layout sir in the bottom

Comment: Make sure that your widget is loaded in moment of initialization. Then reply.

Comment: what do you mean by that sir?

Answer (score 0):

```js
axios.get("api/user").then(({ data }) => {
  this.users = data;
  $(function() {
     $("#table").DataTable({});
  });
});
```